# JSON file transform

Tags: json, azure-pipelines, appsettings

We have 3 json files with a name "ConnectedService.json" and in these 3 json files one URL is going to be vary based on environment wise.

Can anyone help me how we can do file transform through ADO pipeline if we have more than one json file with same name in each file and different values to replace?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [File transform task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines). Setup a variable in your pipeline called URL. Configure the task to look for ConnectedService.json.

```
# File transform v2
- task: FileTransform@2
  inputs:
    folderPath: './**/'
    jsonTargetFiles: 'ConnectedService.json'
```