# NetCore Json Config File Transformation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a definition.json file held at Root of my app, so in the wwwroot folder.  The solution is one code set, but I need this file to be different per environment much like the builder does for the app.settings files.  I can't have multiple definition files, as they need to be called the same name.

I have the top link which is related to builder, but unclear is this is the correct approach as I can only see this related to app.settings.  The bottom link is the only link I can see on this site and is unanswered.

Not sure if I missing an elegant approach to this?

https://blog.elmah.io/config-transformations-in-aspnetcore/

[JSON file transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75721611/json-file-transform)

Comment: Are you specifying an environment at runtime, or do you need to simply update the JSON file at build/deploy time?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are using for your build/deployment process, but during your deployment you could just use PowerShell to update the JSON file with an appropriate value.

```
// definition.json
{
  "environment_value" : "dev"
}
```

PowerShell:

```
$json = Get-Content "definition.json" | ConvertFrom-Json 
$json.environment_value = "production"
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "definition.json"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't consider this as I was hung up on how app.settings works.  I have a number of environments, so I think get contents based on environment variable which the build has available from config manager in VS2022.  then patch the definition.json with the correct version for that build.    Will have a play around.